# Maintain packages build from source

Tags: ros, catkin, rosws, packages

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to know how I get and maintain packages that I have to build from source.

So, I want to use the `hector_quadrotor` package on jade, so I started off trying to install the tutorial package, which was not build for jade, so I build it from source.

This involved me building several other packages from source as well. I don't know if my approach is the way you should do that with ROS (with catkin and jade), so I want to ask how you would do that?

1. So we start off with a catkin workspace (`catkin_ws`) where we want to use a source build package.
2. I follow the tutorial [here](http://wiki.ros.org/hector_quadrotor/Tutorials/Quadrotor%20indoor%20SLAM%20demo) in 1.2 and wsinit a folder in my `catkin_ws/src` folder.
3. If I want to build it, it says that there is a package missing: `hardware_interface`, it turns out that this package is not available for jade (yet), so I go ahead with my "missing package" algorithm which is the following:
4. I go to my `catkin_ws/devel` and do `rosws set <name> --git <url_to_repository_with_package_or_stack>`
5. I update the ws: `rosws update <name>`
6. I re-source: `source catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash`

Now, the silly part comes in: I COPY the package I need from `catkin_ws/devel/<name>/` to `catkin_ws/src/`

So, e.g. for my case `hardware_interface`, I would checkout the `ros_control` (as `<name>`) and just copy everything out from there to my src folder. I can't just leave everything in devel (although it is in the CMAKE path), I have to copy EVERY individual package from the stack folder in devel to my src folder.
That can impossibly be the way how this should work.

I was expecting that I point my workspace to a repository if it couldn't find it and it would download and maintain it on it's own.

I mean, this works, but it is nasty. Please help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/223203/maintain-packages-build-from-source/) by [Borob](https://answers.ros.org/users/23030/borob/) on ROS Answers with karma: 111 on 2015-12-28

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> 2 . I follow the tutorial [here](http://wiki.ros.org/hector_quadrotor/Tutorials/Quadrotor%20indoor%20SLAM%20demo) in 1.2 and wsinit a folder in my `catkin_ws/src` folder.

Ok.

> 3 . If I want to build it, it says that there is a package missing: `hardware_interface`, it turns out that this package is not available for jade (yet), so I go ahead with my "missing package" algorithm which is the following:

`hardware_interface` is actually available on Jade (see [debbuild/jade?q=hardware_interface](http://www.ros.org/debbuild/jade?q=hardware_interface)), just not yet in the public repositories. Building from source is fine, but you may want to see whether you can use the [ros-shadow-fixed](http://wiki.ros.org/ShadowRepository) repository.

> 4 . I go to my `catkin_ws/devel` and do `rosws set <name> --git <url_to_repository_with_package_or_stack>`

You're mixing `wstool` and `rosws`. Don't do that.

The reason you have to go to the `devel` folder is probably related to that.

> 5 . I update the ws: `rosws update <name>`

In a catkin workspace, please only use `wstool`. The arguments for `set` and `update` are the same.

And only do it in your `src` folder (which is where your `.rosinstall` file should be).

> 6 . I re-source: `source catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash`

But only *after* you've rebuilt your workspace .. right?

Finally: maybe you are already doing it, but you don't mention it: I'd recommend running a `rosdep check --from-paths /path/to/your/catkin_ws/src --ignore-src` between steps 5 & 6. That way you'll be sure you have all package dependencies installed, instead of having to find that out during `catkin_make` / `catkin build`.

---

Edit:

> The problem is, that I don't know what tools I should use (wstool over rosws) and which I shouldn't.

I'm slightly confused: I thought I was quite clear when I wrote:

> In a catkin workspace, please only use `wstool`.

Afaik, `rosws` was used with `rosbuild` workspaces, which is why it doesn't work quite so well with catkin.

> Can you please tell me what my approach should be to get and build packages from source in a carkinws?

Basically what you've already been doing, but then only with `wstool`, and no trips to your `devel` space.

A concrete example (with `wstool`):

```
source /opt/ros/../setup.bash
mkdir -p /path/to/a/new/catkin_ws/src
cd /path/to/a/new/catkin_ws/src

wstool init .
wstool set <name> --git <url_to_repository_with_package_or_stack>
wstool up

cd /path/to/a/new/catkin_ws
# alternatively, use 'rosdep install ..' here directly
rosdep check --from-paths /path/to/a/new/catkin_ws/src --ignore-src

catkin_make
source devel/setup.bash
```

Alternatively, you could just do a `git clone <url_to_repository_with_package_or_stack>` in `catkin_ws/src` instead of using `wstool`.  `wstool` comes in handy if you have many repositories to clone, and don't want to do it by hand.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2015-12-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Borob](https://answers.ros.org/users/23030/borob/) on 2015-12-29**:
Thank you very much! The problem is, that I don't know what tools I should use (wstool over rosws) and which I shouldn't. So rosdep is okay with catkin, but rosws and probably ros isn't... Can you please tell me what my approach should be to get and build packages from source in a carkinws?

**Comment by [Borob](https://answers.ros.org/users/23030/borob/) on 2015-12-29**:
Thank you very much, very glad someone shed light on this! Regarding the tools: I know now that I should use wstool over rosws, but my question was: How do I know what tool sets I should use with catkin just from ROS, without asking you?

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2015-12-29**:
@Druff sorry for the confusion. The `wstool` wiki page mentions that it replaces `rosws` for catkin packages: http://wiki.ros.org/wstool This wiki page also uses `wstool` in conjunction with catkin: http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/Tutorials/workspace_overlaying I updated a few wiki pages with a note.

**Comment by [Borob](https://answers.ros.org/users/23030/borob/) on 2015-12-29**:
@William A my bad. Thank you so much!